# Virtual Machine oracle problem wont start

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtual

I'm trying to run VM server on Ubuntu 20.40 lts

When I try run vagrant up I got this message

```
No usable default provider could be found for your system.

Vagrant relies on interactions with 3rd party systems, known as
"providers", to provide Vagrant with resources to run development
environments. Examples are VirtualBox, VMware, Hyper-V.

The easiest solution to this message is to install VirtualBox, which
is available for free on all major platforms.

If you believe you already have a provider available, make sure it
is properly installed and configured. You can see more details about
why a particular provider isn't working by forcing usage with
`vagrant up --provider=PROVIDER`, which should give you a more specific
error message for that particular provider.
```

My VM server version is not showing up: should be Ubuntu 19.10 / 20.04 from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads (it is installed on my system)

```
virtualbox --version

WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (5.8.0-44-generic) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
***:~/Desktop/Shell$
```

My vagrant version

```
Installed Version: 2.2.14
Latest Version: 2.2.14
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you load the kernel module "vboxdrv" ? Please go ahead and run "sudo /sbin/vboxconfig"

Comment: i fonud solution, i distabled key;s